# Trying to figure out what is wrong with my logic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been given this question:
Sam’s last two times for the $10,000$ metres added up to $71.4$ minutes. Her second time was $10\%$ slower than her first. Next season Sam wants to improve her first time by $5\%$

I evaluated in this way:

1st try = $x$

2nd try = $y$

$y = x+10\%$

THEREFORE - I think my formula to evaluate  should be:
$x+(x+10\%)=71.4$

I think this evaluates to $x = 35.65$ minutes
SO - when I then take $x+10\%$ I get $39.215$ and this should be $Y$.

BUT $35.65 + 39.215 = 74.865$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: $x+10\%$ means $1.1x$.

Comment: Intervals of time are not slower or faster but they can be larger or  smaller, Velocities can be slower.

Comment: $y= x + 10% $ is not just wrong but is meaningless.  What you want is $y =.9*x $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TonyK said in the comments $x+10\%$ is equivalent to saying $1.1x$

$$x = \text{ first try}$$
$$y = \text{ second try}$$
$$x + (x\cdot 1.1) = 71.4 \,\,\Rightarrow x=34$$
$$y = 71.4 - x = 37.4 $$

How the formula works:

As you said, if $x$ is the first run, then $x + 10\%$ (x plus ten percent of x) is the time of her second run. Well, $10\%$ of $x$ is the same as saying $\frac{10}{100} \cdot x = 0.1x$. Making $x+0.1x=1.1x$ be the time of the second run. So the sum of the first two attempts ($x + 1.1x$) is the total distance, $x + 1.1x = 71.4$ and solve this for $x$ and you get $x=34$

Comment: sooo - x = 37.578947

Comment: If that is correct then y must equal 33.821053

Comment: BUT in the original question y being the 2nd try is actually 10% longer in time than x?

Comment: my fault. I labeled it incorrectly

Comment: @kiltannen I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you HEAPS - so that would make the solution to the overall problem being Sam's target is 32 min 18sec.   Thank you for your help!  I will need to come back to this a bit later to fully understand how you arrived at 34...  AS IN - I need to figure out how this formula needs to work.